# How can I print something conditionally on node.tpl.php depending on what taxonomy term the node is tagged with?

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, nodes, theming

For example, I would like to print something only when the currently viewed node is tagged with tid = 100. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this...

```
<?php if ($node->taxonomy[100]): ?> 
    print anything here 
<?php endif; ?>
```